# Core plot osx not plotting

Tags: graph, plot, core-plot

I'm writing a simple cocoa app for a school project which requires to graph some data from a serial port and plot it into a simple graph. I have chosen for Core- Plot as framework to generate and display the dataplots, however I can't get it to work.

I managed to get the axis drawn and the program runs fine, but there are no data lines appearing. I use the following code:

```
#import "Controller.h"
#import <CorePlot/CorePlot.h>

@implementation Controller

-(void)dealloc
{
    [plotData release];
    [graph release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

// Create graph from theme
graph = [(CPTXYGraph *)[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme];
[graph applyTheme:theme];
hostView.hostedGraph = graph;

// Setup scatter plot space
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(-1) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(10)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(-1) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(10.0)];


// Axes
// Label x axis with a fixed interval policy
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
x.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromString(@"1");
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0.0");
x.minorTicksPerInterval       = 2;

x.title         = @"Tijd (s)";
x.titleOffset   = 30.0;
x.titleLocation = CPTDecimalFromString(@"8.5");

// Label y with an automatic label policy.
CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.labelingPolicy              = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0.0");
y.minorTicksPerInterval       = 2;
y.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 8;
y.labelOffset                 = 10.0;

y.title         = @"Kracht (N)";
y.titleOffset   = 30.0;
y.titleLocation = CPTDecimalFromString(@"8");

// Create a plot that uses the data source method
CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
dataSourceLinePlot.identifier = @"Date Plot";

CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [[dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy] autorelease];
lineStyle.lineWidth              = 3.f;
lineStyle.lineColor              = [CPTColor greenColor];
dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;

dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
[graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];

// Add some data
NSMutableArray *contentArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for ( NSUInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    id x = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:i];
    id y = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:1.2];
    [contentArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x, @"x", y, @"y", nil]];
    NSLog(@"waarde %@", contentArray);
}
NSLog(@"plotting");
plotData = [contentArray retain];
}


-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
return plotData.count;
}


@end
```

The code is based of one of the examples.

The NSLog(@"waarde %@", contentArray); returns a good looking array, containing correct datapoints.

Comment: have you implemented the numberForPlot:field:recordIndex method?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
hostView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:hostView];
```

Is that fact that it is not appearing due to the fact you haven't added it as a view?

Comment: Hello Mark, Thanks for the response, however i get a error message when i try to compile the code. "Property 'view' not found on object of type 'Controller *' ". Any suggestions?

Comment: Ahh just seen Andrew's comments, check that you have implemented all the datasource methods such as numberForPlot:field:recordIndex and numberOfRecordsForPlot:plot

Comment: If you are able to draw the axis, the problem isn't getting it onto the screen it is probably the datasource methods that you have missed

Comment: Thanks, i actually implemented those but i mistyped "(fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX ? @"x" : @"y")" 

Many thanks for all the help.